# React Native Image show blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, frontend

i am using react native and i want to display an image, and here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const Class = ({ route }) => {
  const { classname } = route.params;
  const [studentList, setStudentList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://192.168.47.102:5000/students/from/class/${classname}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setStudentList(json.docs);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(err);
        Alert.alert(err.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={studentList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.studentListContainer}>
              <Text>{item.fullname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.studentCode}>{item.code}</Text>
              <Text>{item.profileImage}</Text>
              {/* <View>
                <Image
                  style={styles.studentAvatar}
                  source={{ uri: item.profileImage }}
                />
              </View> */}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return item._id;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  studentListContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "#bbb",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: "dashed",
  },
  studentCode: {
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  studentAvatar: { width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 50 / 2 },
});

export default Class;
```

and this is how it rendered:

[image: render with Text]

as you can see i have the text displaying url of image to prove that url is valid, after that i comment the snippet code render image url and replace it with image tag like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const Class = ({ route }) => {
  const { classname } = route.params;
  const [studentList, setStudentList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://192.168.47.102:5000/students/from/class/${classname}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setStudentList(json.docs);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(err);
        Alert.alert(err.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={studentList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.studentListContainer}>
              <Text>{item.fullname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.studentCode}>{item.code}</Text>
              {/* <Text>{item.profileImage}</Text> */}
              <View>
                <Image
                  style={styles.studentAvatar}
                  source={{ uri: item.profileImage }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return item._id;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  studentListContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "#bbb",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: "dashed",
  },
  studentCode: {
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  studentAvatar: { width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 50 / 2 },
});

export default Class;
```

and this is how it rendered:

[image: render without text]

as you can see it can not display anything, please help me to make it visible, thank you for help me out, have a good day

Comment: What is the response of request?

Comment: please help me to make it visible, thank you so much

Comment: what is the value in "item.profileImage" key

Comment: It is a string , i have mentioned that in the first picture, please take a read AGAIN, thank you so much

Comment: Please provide the exact image URL while in the pic it's not clear the complete URL. Might be something wrong with URL

Comment: here it is:

https://avataaars.io/?accessoriesType=Prescription01&avatarStyle=Circle&clotheColor=Blue02&clotheType=BlazerSweater&eyeType=WinkWacky&eyebrowType=FlatNatural&facialHairColor=Platinum&facialHairType=MoustacheFancy&hairColor=Platinum&hatColor=PastelRed&mouthType=Vomit&skinColor=Brown&topType=LongHairMiaWallace

Comment: Your code seems perfect. I have tried working fine